# how to setup an AbstractNumbering for bulleted Lists

Tags: ms-word, docx4j

I want to generate unordered lists in a Word document with `docx4j`. Can anybody give me an example of an `AbstractNumbering` for bulleted lists?

```
public void setAbstractNumbering(){
    try {
        NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
        myword.addTargetPart(ndp);
        Numbering.AbstractNum abstractNum = factory.createNumberingAbstractNum();
        abstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        Numbering.AbstractNum.MultiLevelType multiLevelType = new Numbering.AbstractNum.MultiLevelType();
        abstractNum.setMultiLevelType(multiLevelType);
        multiLevelType.setVal("singleLevel");
        Lvl lvl = factory.createLvl();
        abstractNum.getLvl().add(lvl);
        lvl.setIlvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
        Lvl.Start start = new Lvl.Start();
        lvl.setStart(start);
        start.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        NumFmt numFmt = factory.createNumFmt();
        lvl.setNumFmt(numFmt);
        numFmt.setVal(NumberFormat.BULLET);
        Lvl.LvlText text = new Lvl.LvlText();
        lvl.setLvlText(text);
        text.setVal("%1");

        Numbering.Num numbering = ndp.addAbstractListNumberingDefinition(abstractNum);
        Numbering.Num.AbstractNumId abstractNumId = new Numbering.Num.AbstractNumId();
        abstractNumId.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        numbering.setAbstractNumId(abstractNumId);
        numbering.setNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(3));

    } catch (InvalidFormatException ife){
        ife.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I'm currently getting a `NullPointerException` when adding the `abstractNumbering` to the `NumberingDefinitionsPart`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After creating a part, you need to populate it.  So after ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart(), try ndp.setContents(new Numbering() );

Answer (score 0):

[ListHelper.java#L155](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/ListHelper.java#L155)

You need a Numbering Definition Instance which points to it; see further [ecma376/WordML/numbering_2.html](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/numbering_2.html)

The easiest way to get code is to create a simple docx in Word, then use the docx4j webapp or Helper Word AddIn to generate code from the numbering definitions part in that docx.

Comment: i also get the NullPointerException at the same instruction when i use the ListHelper